# Rooting from the Appdelegate to Viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

`UIApplicationDelegate` - in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` checking for user authentication if authenticated making the network call and in the response block writing the rooting code as per the success and failure conditions for success rooting to Home screen(landing screen) and for failure rooting to login screen. But i'm facing flipping issue , it's not rooting properly , for success condition it's showing initial viewcontroller and landing to home viewcontroller.

```
if dev_token == deviceToken{
//  Constants.setValueInUserDefaults(objValue: "no", for: "logincheck")                        
    if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as? SWRevealViewController {
         if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
             var currentController = rootViewController
             while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
                 currentController = presentedController
             }
             currentController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
          }
     }
}else{
    self.goToLogin()
    //Constants.setValueInUserDefaults(objValue: "yes", for: "logincheck")                                        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> checking for user authentication if authenticated making the network
>   call and in the response block writing the rooting code

Don't apply this behavior in the AppDelegate/`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, *move* this step into a new different view controller.

What you could do instead is to make an initial splash scene (view controller) and let it always be the root, therefore you could determine the root view controller after getting the response from the network call.

Moreover, it would be a good idea to follow this approach because you will be able to display an indicator in the splash scene, giving an indication that there is "something" to be waited.

Comment: can we create a viewcontroller class for launch screen?

Comment: @SunilKumar no you can't. That's why you should create a new view controller.

Comment: i had removed launching screen and created custom splash viewcontroller in storyboard and there i called network call in viewdidload() , still the rooting transition is not happening properly.

Comment: i should do network call before roots to the login or landing screen by validating with user logged in session.